# is homestead is compulsory for laravel development

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently learning frameworks in php. I decided to try laravel.

i have tried its installation and routing example. while next step it says  **homestead** installation instructions over there. It looks like any virtual machine to be installed . [homestead description link](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/homestead)

I want to know is it compulsory laravel should be use with homestead? 
if i don't use is there any effects on my code efficiency or performance?

Comment: No it isn't compulsory.... I set up my own environment for developing with Laravel to replicate my production environment as closely as possible; but homestead saves you a lot of time and effort in setting up a VM by hand.... as for efficiency/performance of a "homebrew" development environment, that's entirely down to the way you set it up, and not a question that anybody but yourself can answer

Comment: @MarkBaker ok now i got it. it is for simulating our production server. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Homestead is not compulsory. You can run Laravel with any common web server as long as you hit the proper requirements.

But Homestead does greatly ease the difficulty of having to setup a development environment, and it also lets you closely mimic your production server as to make the whole Download->Develop->Deploy process seamless.

Laravel Forge is a service that lets you manage your servers and set them up in such a way that almost mirrors Homestead. To See more, Go to the [Laravel Forge Homepage](http://forge.laravel.com)